# Image not working with Next Gen gallery plugin

Tags: wordpress

After I moved my site from a sub directory to another, the images are not working in my gallery. I'm using the Next Gen Gallery plugin. All other images and content are working on the site after the move.

To solve this I deactivated and erased the Next Gen plugin and dowloaded it again and installed it and then uploaded the images again. But still not working. When I select Manage Galleries I can only see the file names of the images, but not the images.

I also tried to run the plugin Update urls with this option URLs in page content posts, pages, custom post types, revisions.

What could be wrong and how can I get it to work again?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the URL in Image Options?

Reference: http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/image-options/

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but this looks ok. What else could be wrong?

Comment: I discovered that all new galleries that I have tried to upload images, are in the old directory for the site! Then I changed the path for the URL, but then when I look with the FTP, the folder isn't created! I'm very confused :(  ??

Comment: I am not exactly sure why changing the URL in NextGen Gallery is not working. You could use a WordPress plugin like [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) or phpMyAdmin to search for all old url:s and replace them with the correct one.

Comment: When I try to view an image from inside the gallery I get a path that is double like: example.com/folder/http:/example.com/folder/wp-content/gallery/test/image.jpg Is there still some issues from when I moved the site to another directory?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long time.

I encountered this error and one thing I noticed is that including some characters in the gallery name will result in “no images were found” error.

Ensure that your gallery name does not have any of these characters: **‘”(&@/**

For example: So if you have a gallery with 'MEET & GREET EVENT GALLERY' as name, the page won't load properly.

Remove the characters and try again, it should work fine.